Solve SDE $dS_t=(a-b\ln S_t)S_tdt+\sigma S_tdW_t$
Solve the SDE:
$dS_t=(a-b\ln S_t)S_tdt+\sigma S_tdW_t$
Where $a$, $b$ and $\sigma$ are constants
I believe I need to use Ito's lemma.
$df=\big( \frac{df}{dt} + (a-b \ln S_t)S_t\frac{df}{dS_t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 S^2_t \frac{d^2f}{dS^2_t} \big)dt +\sigma S_t \frac{df}{dS_t}dW_t$
Edit:
Let $f=\ln S_t$
$d(\ln S_t)=\big(a-b\ln S_t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\big)dt+\sigma dW_t$
How do I eliminate $S_t$ from the right hand side of the equation?

Perhaps dividing by $S_t$ will lead somewhere.

Hint: the choice $f(S_t) = \ln S_t$ will lead you to a well-known SDE.
